# Is it possible to merge unity scenes with windows apps?

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-game-engine, windows-store-apps

I am working on a windows application for educational purposes.
My application consists of more than one window/page, each page has a specific job such as showing information, drawing and voice recognition.
Some pages/windows can only be done in Visual Studio windows apps (WPF or Windows store) such as pages with Kinect V2 functions.
However, there are some pages/windows that are much easier to do in Unity3D than in visual studio.

Is there a way to merge the unity 3D scenes windows app pages in one application?
The result I am looking for is a windows application (WPF or Store app) that consists of many pages, some of them are developed with visual studio and others developed with Unity engine.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you generate a Windows Store app from Unity it generates a Visual Studio Solution which you can then edit as desired. The Unity scene will run as a SwapChainPanel in the initial Xaml page. You can add your own Xaml and C# or C++ around it and can bridge between the Windows Runtime and Unity environments.

I haven't tried running multiple Xaml pages with Unity, but I expect it will work, although you may need to take care to keep Unity's environment stable. You may need to keep Unity's SwapChainPanel on a single page and manage different scenes for it within Unity rather than using separate Xaml pages for different scenes, and you probably need to start with Unity if you're using the free version so that the required splash-screen appears.

Another possibility--especially if Unity doesn't like having its SwapChainPanel messed with--would be to keep everything on one master Xaml page with the SwapChainPanel and a Frame containing the real Xaml pages.

If the only limit on using Unity is Kinect then there is a [Kinect for Windows plug-in for Unity](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=513177). It required the pro version of Unity 4, but not (I think) for Unity 5.